# Continuity of piecewise function defined for rationals and irrationals

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know the similarity of the next function with Thomae's function, but how should I formalize using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ criterion the continuity of the function
$$ f(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
2-t^2 & \text{if} & t\in\mathbb Q\\
t^2-2 & \text{if} & t\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q
\end{array}
\right. $$
Thanks.

Comment: do you see which are the points where the function is continuous?

Comment: First figure out **what** is going on. Wild behaviour almost everywhere, sign flips like crazy. Except flipping sign doesn't do much when we are near $\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, that is clear to me, but seems hard to me formalizing this reasoning.

Comment: What is t ? Did you mean x ?

Comment: @nonlinearism corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Pick any rational point $t_0 \in \Bbb R - \{\pm\sqrt{2}\}$ and put $\epsilon < \frac{1}{2}|(t_0^2 - 2) - (2 - t_0^2)| = \frac{1}{2}|2t_0^2 - 4|$.

Since $g_1(t) = t^2 - 2$ is continuous, we can find $\delta_1$ so that:

$$
|t - t_0| < \delta_1 \implies |(t^2 - 2) - (t_0^2 - 2)| < \epsilon
$$

Now, for any $\delta > 0$, no matter how big or small, we can find an irrational number $t_1$ that satisfies both of the following simultaneously: $|t_0 - t_1| < \delta_1, |t_0 - t_1| < \delta$.

We have:

\begin{align}
|f(t_1) - f(t_0)| &= |(t_1^2 - 2) - (2 - t_0^2)| = |(t_1^2 - 2) - (t_0^2 - 2) + (t_0^2 - 2) - (2 - t_0^2)| \\
&\ge |(t_0^2 - 2) - (2 - t_0^2)| - |(t_1^2 - 2) - (t_0^2 - 2)| \\
&\ge 2 \epsilon - \epsilon = \epsilon
\end{align}

Thus, $f$ is not continuous at $t_0$. A similar argument works for irrational points in $\Bbb R - \{\pm\sqrt{2}\}$.

Why doesn't this argument work for $\{\pm\sqrt{2}\}$? Can you show continuity at these two points?